# How to gather company data from VIES database via SOAP

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I am using the VIES database to gather company data, based on European VAT number for my PHP application.

The things that I need are:

- city
- street name
- house number
- postcode
- comapny name

as separate data but the VIES database is giving me all of it as a one string.

Working example:

```
<?php
try {
    $opts = array(
        'http' => array(
            'user_agent' => 'PHPSoapClient'
        )
    );
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);

    $client = new SoapClient(
        'http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl',
        array('stream_context' => $context,
              'cache_wsdl'     => WSDL_CACHE_NONE)
    );

    $result = $client->checkVat(
        array(
            'countryCode' => 'PL',
            'vatNumber'   => '5242106963'
        )
    );
    print_r($result);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

I am receiving:

```
stdClass Object (
    [countryCode] => PL
    [vatNumber] => 5242106963
    [requestDate] => 2015-02-20+01:00
    [valid] => 1
    [name] => COCA-COLA HBC POLSKA SPÓŁKA Z OGRANICZONĄ ODPOWIEDZIALNOŚCIĄ
    [address] => ANNOPOL 20 03-236 WARSZAWA
)
```

But I need the address like this:

```
$street='ANNOPOL';
$number='20';
$city='WARSZAWA';
$postcode='03-236';
```

Also please keep in mind that for other companies, the street name or city can have more then one word, like "New York", so an easy solution to divide the data based on space between words doesn't work for me.

Comment: The first link doesn't point to anything that shows an example of "giving ... all of that as a one text". Can you remove the link and add in an example record?

Comment: If you want to receive structured data, SOAP is a good approach. Do their EU sites have a manual or a developers area to show you how to make a SOAP call to their service? Your question is likely to be put on hold as it stands, as there is no code to assist with, and it is rather broad. If you can therefore give it a go, that will give readers something to advise upon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have stated that postal code will be in `99-999` format and assuming the street number (+ any flat identification) will always start with a number, you can use a preg_match to parse the address string:

```
$result = new stdClass();
$result->address = 'Wita Stwosza 15 M5 31-042 Kraków';

preg_match(
    '#'
    . '(.*?)'             // Match as many chars as possible (street)
    . '\s+(\d+(?:.*?))'   // Space, then number and possibly flat (number)
    . '\s+(\d\d\-\d\d\d)' // Space, then digits/dash/digits (postcode)
    . '\s(.*)'            // Space, then everything after that (city)
    . '#',
    $result->address,
    $matches
);
list ($street, $number, $postcode, $city) = array_slice($matches, 1);

echo "Street:   $street", PHP_EOL;
echo "Number:   $number", PHP_EOL;
echo "Postcode: $postcode", PHP_EOL;
echo "City:     $city", PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
Street:   Wita Stwosza
Number:   15 M5
Postcode: 31-042
City:     Kraków
```

Comment: Very interesting solution, however I am not sure if this will be universal.
For example another data from VIES:

Wita Stwosza 15 M5 31-042 Kraków

So we have always format like:
Street Number Postcode City
What is important the Posctode is always 2 gigits, dash and 3 digits. Ex 12-345

The only problem is street name and number.
In this scenario "Wita Stwosza" is a street, and "15 M5" is a number and flat.
..but even street name with number will be ok.

So how to split 'Wita Stwosza 15 M5 31-042 Kraków' by the Street+Number, Postcode, City

Comment: Wita Stwosza 15 M5 31-042 Kraków

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see the VIES data already has newlines built into the result. So you should be able to explode based upon the newline character. Then it will just be a case of working out if the postcode is last or the city.

To confirm what I am saying just:

```
echo nl2br($result->address);
```